Is a search warrant no good if they forgot to name on the warrant what it was to be seized and looked for?
The police show up at my door with search warrant for dang cell phone battery. First, the warrant does not name the items to looked for and seized and it’s unreasonable when it has no bearing on the case whatsoever. They denied me the right to call a lawyer and when my boyfriend tried to call one they snatched his phone and detained him and took the phone that was recording all this and deleted the video. There was 5 cops show up for this warrant 3 city cops and 2 county cops. The city cops were out of jurisdiction and the one county officer I don’t believe was even on duty but was still there searching. What can I do about these cops it’s ridiculous.

I'm really sorry you're going through this. As written, though, this question is asking for personal legal advice and we can't be your lawyer for such things. It honestly sounds like you need to hire an attorney to intervene on your behalf. If you can add a location tag, we may be able to point you to appropriate resources for an attorney.

What is a "dang cell phone battery"? How do you know that's what the warrant is for if it's not on the warrant?

@Barmar It's a battery for a mobile phone. It stores and converts energy so the phone can be used without being connected to an electrical outlet. You can learn more about this technology here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery

@bdb484 Why would the police bother to execute a search for a cell phone battery? What kind of evidence would it have? A cell phone would be reasonable.  Learn about why one would ask the question here.

germany
If an otherwise legal search yields evidence of a different crime, called a Zufallsfund (random discovery, §108 StPO), then this may be used  if the means of search would have been permissible for the different crime. This distinction matters e.g. for wiretaps, which are only allowed for enumerated crimes, while physical searches would in principle be applicable to any crime.
So if a wiretap which had been authorized on the suspicion of drug dealing yields evidence of fare evasion, this cannot be used. If a physical search which had been authorized on the suspicion of drug dealing, this can be used.

Nothing in the question is about finding evidence related to a different crime (it doesn't even say what the crime is).

@Barmar, the OP wrote about a battery which had no bearing on the case. For a generic answer, I'm assuming that is the case, and not a misunderstanding.

The question is so confusing (to me) I'm not sure how any answer can be given.

@Barmar, I agree it is confusing, but the issues seem to be first the scope of the search warrant and what was found, second being allowed to contact a lawyer during the search, third the recording, and finally the question of jurisdiction in a multi-agency search.
